# Upload Files transactional with SFTP?

Tags: ftp, sftp

I want to upload files to a SFTP-Server transactional, so if one upload fails it should fail completely (other already successful uploaded files in this batch should also vanish/fail).

Is this possible? So far it looks like this isn't possible out of the box and I need to implement this on my own. Is there any library which implements this?

I prefer C#/.net libraries but mark this question only with a general ftp tag, since I want to know if this is supported by the protocol itself. Any other libraries/github-links are welcome.

Thanks!

## What I've done so far

- googled for "sftp transaction"/"ftp transaction"/"ftp batch"
- found only mput (simultaneous upload of files), but this doesn't seem to be transactional ("all or nothing")